# tvOS, swift: how to restore default gesture recognizer

Tags: swift, button, menu, tvos, apple-tv

i have in SpriteKit 2 SkViews.
The first is the menu scene, the second is the gamescene.
By default the menu button of siri remote send user back to Apple TV main screen.
So in my second view (game scene) i initialized a gesturerecognizer to go back to menu scene. The problem is when i'm back to the menu scene, the menu button doesnt sent me back to Apple TV main screen anymore and stay on the menu scene.

How may i restore default behaviour of menu button when i'm back to menu scene?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

After you return to the menu scene, you should remove or disable your gesture recognizer. If the user returns to the game scene, you should re-add or re-enable that gesture.

If any gesture recognizes the Menu button, UIKit won't let the app exit (because it thinks that you're handling the Menu button, so it doesn't want to interfere) even if your handler doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you return to the main menu scene make sure you disable the gesture recognizer

in objective C

`myGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;`

in Swift

```
myGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
```

hope this helps